# Is "Running without renderer sandbox" an error?

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefglue

On Windows 7, I started a C# browser offscreen application project.
I'm using

- latest versions of the Xilium.CefGlue(xilium-xilium.cefglue-3caa551bd830)
- Cef binary (cef_binary_3.2171.2039_windows32).

I do this CEF settings

```
var cefSettings = new CefSettings
{
    SingleProcess = false,
    MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true,
    LogSeverity = CefLogSeverity.Disable,
    LogFile = "TestOffScrennCefGlue.log"
};
```

But this error message is displayed in console window

```
[0325/185611:ERROR:renderer_main.cc(207)] Running without renderer sandbox
```

Is this error message normal?

Why this error message is displayed in console window?

**EDIT:** *Following the comment from Claies:*

The sandbox got introduced in CEFs 1750 branch.
I have tried setting

```
NoSandbox = true
```

(in `cefSettings`) and still get the same result which is kinda strange.

I find this [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) with `--no-sandbox` switch (Disables the sandbox for all process types that are normally sandboxed) but I don't know how to set this switch in xilium cefglue.

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/501